Image width is 0 when using absolute property paired with relative
I'm experiencing some issues with displaying images that have an absolute position. The parent div has a relative position, and the two images have an absolute position. I'm using an inline SVG import as the image source. When I remove the absolute positioning from the image, it renders correctly.
Here's the code I'm working with:
<div class="flex h-20 w-full">
    <div class="relative mt-1">
        <img class="absolute left-4 top-4 h-12 w-12" src={Polygon} alt="" />
        <img class="absolute left-4 top-2 h-12 w-12" src={Polygon1} alt="" />
    </div>
</div>

Edit:
It seems like both the image itself and the parent div with "relative" positioning have a width of 0.

what is the problem?

@AhmedAbdelbaset As I mentioned in the post, whenever I apply the absolute class name to the img, it doesn't render. Esentially the height of the image is 0 when I hover it in dev tools.

That's because the flex in the parent. Flex gives the children as less space as it need. Since the child (<div class="relative mt-1">) has only absolute elements (<img class="absolute...) Its width is 0.
To fix it give the child (<div class="relative mt-1">) some width
<div class="flex h-20 w-full">
    <div class="relative mt-1 w-40">
        <img class="absolute left-4 top-4 h-12 w-12" src="http://ipsum.photos/get/400" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>

Working Demo: https://play.tailwindcss.com/rSCJbZQmuD
